# Why is the rank of a $n \times n$ square matrix of the first positive integers from the smallest until $n^2$ always equal $2$ for $n≥2$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I tried it out on a $3\times 3$ and a $4\times 4$ matrix and saw that from the third line on all lines are multiples of the second line, so only the first two lines are unique.

E.g. for a $3\times 3$ matrix until $3^2$:
$$\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{matrix} \right) \Rightarrow \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 0 & 3 & 6\\ 0 & 6 & 12 \end{matrix} \right).$$

However, I don't understand why it is the case and how it would be possible to prove the above statement.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Subtract the first row from all the other rows

Comment: How can one prove it formally though?

Comment: Formally, according to what @daw suggested, you go from $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & \dots &n\\ n+1 & n+2 & \dots & 2 n\\2n+1&2n+2 &\dots&3n\\ &&\ddots &\\n(n-1) + 1 & n(n-1) + 2 & \dots & n^{2} \end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & \dots &n\\ n & n & \dots & n\\2n&2n &\dots&2n\\ &&\ddots &\\n(n-1)  & n(n-1)  & \dots & n (n-1) \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Greta The argument from daw shows that the rank is at most $2$. It remains to show that the rank cannot be $1$, which is easy. Nothing more has to be done.

Comment: Thank you so much!!